# How to select specific div using BeautifulSoup when multiple divs have the same class name no id tag?

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Please help I don't know how to select specific div using BeautifulSoup when multiple divs have the same class name no id tag.

Web page that I am trying to scrape: https://www.helpmefind.com/rose/l.php?l=2.65689.

I want to select contents of specific divs independently and then pass to a csv file. Got stuck since find_all returns multiple divs and I don't know how to restrict further.

```
rose_div = rose.find_all("div", class_="hdg")
```

Returns:

```
[<div class="hdg">HMF Ratings:</div>, <div class="hdg">Origin:</div>, <div class="hdg">Class:</div>, <div class="hdg">Bloom:</div>, <div class="hdg">Parentage:</div>, <div   class="hdg">Notes:</div>, <div class="hdg"> </div>]
```

I want to select individually below divs:

```
<div class="hdg">Origin:</div>

<div class="hdg">Class:</div>

<div class="hdg">Bloom:</div>

<div class="hdg">Parentage:</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS selector `div.hdg:contains("Origin:")` to select `<div>` with `class="hdg"` that contains word "Origing:". To get next element with class `grp`, you can add `+ .grp`.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.helpmefind.com/rose/l.php?l=2.65689'
soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser' )

origin = soup.select_one('div.hdg:contains("Origin:") + .grp').text
class_ = soup.select_one('div.hdg:contains("Class:") + .grp').text
bloom = soup.select_one('div.hdg:contains("Bloom:") + .grp').text
parentage = soup.select_one('div.hdg:contains("Parentage:") + .grp').text

print(origin)
print(class_)
print(bloom)
print(parentage)
```

Prints:

```
Bred by Arai (Japan, before 2009). 
Floribunda.  
Light pink and white, yellow stamens.  Single (4-8 petals), cluster-flowered bloom form.  Blooms in flushes throughout the season.  
If you know the parentage of this rose, or other details, please contact us.
```